# Linked tables with slicer

Tags: powerbi

I have 1 table

that has these data

```
ID  Code    Value   Group
1   KJ13    571 Finance,HR
2   KJ82    415 Operation,Finance
3   TF72    454 HR,Operation,Finance
4   KJ58    362 Operation
5   ND77    607 HR,Finance
6   KJ83    350 Operation,HR
7   TF96    531 Finance
8   YT39    840 HR,Finance
9   SS34    976 Finance,HR
10  ND26    155 Operation,Finance
```

I am filtering by Group through slicer

due to business requirements , slicer has to be in a seperate page

to have slicer for groups

I created a copy of the original table and split it by comma

both the copy and the original one are linked by the ID

my problem is that when I filter by group the origonal table does not filter

I have attached pbix file to make it clearer

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6fb4c8a43b14ed9455f28e40851d8c5020191025022256/567b8d

I appreciate if some one can tell me how to make original table filter based on the slicer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another forum

I am putting it here so it can help someone else with the same problem.

The solution is to change the Relationship between both tables

```
From Cross filter direction : Single
```

to

```
From Cross filter direction : Both
```

Answer (score 0):

At the ribbon go to `View > Sync slicers`. Now you get on the right side your Sync slicers pane. Here you should see your slicer name and the page names. You can check now the checkbox, to sync your slicer from `PageA` to `PageB`. This way, if you change the value in the slicer on `PageA` the charts get also filtered on `PageB`.

Comment: This is how it is already. and still does not filter. I have attached the pbix file

Comment: Ok I see your `Group` column is not directly linked to the copied comma table. This way your slicer doesnt work, because you filter after `Finance` but the other table doenst have `Finance`. But if these two are linked by ID you can go to `Manage Relationship` and drag and drop the ID to create the relationship between this to tables. When the relationship is created and you enable both way filtering it should work.

Comment: The relationship already created, it is 1 to many. and still filter does not work

Comment: Another way is if you dont create a comma separated table and just use the table like it is. This way it works with the sync slicers and if you want to display values with comma separated it is better to create a new column in the query designer with your desired output.